# question for lemma 4 of the BGV paper

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, lattice-crypto

I would like to ask a question that arose when reading the proof of lemma 4 on page 10 of [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/277.pdf) BGV paper:

The assumption is:

[image: assumption]

And the inequality:

[image: inequality]

So it seems that

$$ \sum_{j=1}^{n} \parallel c'[j]-(p/q) \cdot c[j] \parallel \cdot \parallel s[j] \parallel \space = \space \parallel [<c',s>]_p \parallel - \space (p/q) \space \cdot \parallel [<c,s>]_q \space \parallel $$

But why does it hold? It seems that for the left side of the equation, all terms of $j$ is positive, where for some terms of the right side may be negative?

*TIA*

Comment: The image wont show, no matter how I try, sorry for the inconvenience